# Will a DS18B20 Adapter Module for Arduino work on Raspberry Pi 4B?

Tags: arduino, ds18b20

I am new to electronics and the basics are rather beyond me. Excuse me if I ask a simple question.

I understand that usually, Arduino adapters are not compatible with Raspberry Pi, but this looks like it could be.

I have a [Temperature Sensor - Waterproof (DS18B20)](https://core-electronics.com.au/temperature-sensor-waterproof-ds18b20.html) that I want to connect to a Raspberry Pi 4B.

Can I use this [adapter for Arduino](https://www.pixelelectric.com/sensors/temp-humidity-gas-environmental/temperature-humidity/ds18b20-adapter-module-for-arduino/) that has the pull-up resister built into the adapter and connect the sensor to the Raspberry Pi?

I want to avoid using a pull-up resister and a breadboard arrangement.

TYIA.

Comment: If you power it from 3.3V you should have no problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably.

The module has a pull to Vcc.  So Vcc will be applied to the data GPIO.  A Pi GPIO will be destroyed by 5 volts.  That means **you must power the unit with 3.3 volts** rather than 5 volts.